# What is the frequency measurement range of a NanoVNA?

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna, vna, antenna-array, patch-antenna

I have tried to measure a fabricated patch antenna which has theoretically multiband ranging from 1 GHz to 8 GHz, but when I tried to measure it through NanoVNA it barely shows the result from 1 GHz to 4.4 GHz. Is there a limit in the NanoVNA or am I just making a mistake every time?

Comment: Which NanoVNA?  There have been several versions and upgrades since the first NanoVNA came out.

Comment: nano vna-F  V2 by sysjoint